# Send dictionary with socket.send and str.encode()

Tags: python, sockets, dictionary

I'm trying to send an dictionary with `socket.send` but this function takes binary string, i tried to do:

```
test = {"key":"value", "key2":"value2"}
test = str(test).encode()
test.send()
```

The server have just to do:

```
dict = client.recv(1024)
dict = dict(dict.decode())
```

But when i try to get the dictionary from an string i get this error:

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have shadowed the builtin `dict` type by binding name `dict` to `client.recv`, which you *must* not do.

Now, the `dict()` constructor does not take a string as argument. You can use `ast.literal_eval` instead:

```
In [25]: d = '{1: 2, 3: 4}'

In [26]: import ast

In [27]: ast.literal_eval(d)
Out[27]: {1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Comment: Think what happens if somebody figures out how to send `import os;os.system('rm -rf /')` to your socket, though. Maybe look at `pickle` and friends for a safer alternative. JSON would also work.